# Top and Bottom border-image disappear with flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I have gradient border-image for two divs which to I used flex properties.
Problem is this: border disappears from top and bottom in chrome, but works fine in firefox. I have dabblet and code below. The dabblet works in firefox too, but not in chrome.
Also I know the code is bit messy, but I will focus on cleaning it up later.

http://dabblet.com/gist/9642c185857b20cd6720

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="item1">
        <h3>Item</h3>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Item
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button id="buybottlecollector" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Stuff</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="item2">
        <h3>Item2</h3>
        <p>Item2</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.row{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex; 
}

.item1{
    flex: 0 1 40%;
    margin: 5% ; /* 5% */
    padding: 15px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient (to bottom, grey, #f5f5f5) 1 100%;
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(grey, #f5f5f5) 1 100%; 
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(grey), to(#f5f5f5)) 1 100%; 
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(grey, #f5f5f5) 1 100%; 
    -o-border-image: -o-linear-gradient(grey, #f5f5f5) 1 100%;
}


.item2{
    flex: 0 1 40%;
    margin: 5%;
    padding: 15px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient (to bottom, grey, #f5f5f5) 1 100%;
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(grey, #f5f5f5) 1 100%; 
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(grey), to(#f5f5f5)) 1 100%; 
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(grey, #f5f5f5) 1 100%; 
    -o-border-image: -o-linear-gradient(grey, #f5f5f5) 1 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial and error, following dabblet works: http://dabblet.com/gist/489b8f81b188a88d4bf4

I noticed that you wrote -prefix-ed declarations after the unprefixed one so I removed them and *uhoh* the latter didn't work while it should in Chrome v20+

You need:

- to remove whitespace between gradient and opening parenthesis `linear-gradient(`
- to replace the border-image-repeat value you used (100%) by `stretch` (seems like only keywords are valid, not percentages)

`border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, grey, yellow) 1 stretch;` works in Chrome (and then it's a matter of Autoprefixer or http://pleeease.io/play/ to add needed prefixes, if any)

Resources:

- [border-image](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#border-image) from *W3C CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3*
- [border-image-repeat](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/border-image-repeat) at Webplatform
- [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image)

Comment: Thank you! Seems like it wasn't big deal, but I guess I was trying too long and didn't try the simplest changes first. But I must wonder, I used that pleeease.io/play for prefixes (thanks for that link!) and one of it's suggestions was `-webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, grey, #f5f5f5) 1 stretch;` and it seems to give the border-image to whole div background. Why is that? Ofc I just don't use that one and it's fine, just wondering. Also again thank you!

Comment: I don't know: probably a Blink or WebKit bug (that may have been submitted to their bugzilla)? I can't remember having used border-image in a project so really can't tell :)